# Foreground extraction with colors , not threshold(Opencv.js)

Tags: javascript, opencv

I've used the below tutorial to do background subtraction. https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/de/df4/...

Basically, I want to extract subtract background and get foreground objects with color, not threshold.And I do some research on google.I find a similar question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3... But I can't find the frame.copyTo function on OPENCV.js.

How can I do Foreground extraction with colors?

How can I do that with opencv.js?